# Printing pattern from list in Java

Tags: java, list

What I have done here is taken the contents of the table below and stored them in a list called `tableElems`

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35

List<WebElement> tableElems = chrome.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

From this table I want to print in a pattern starting at the 4th element (#3 in the table) and I want to print 3 elements, then skip the next 6, print the next 3 and then skip the next 6, etc. etc.

So my expected output would be `3 4 5 12 13 14 21 22 23 30 31 32`

My initial attempt ended with

```
for (int i = 3; i<tableElems.size(); i++) {
            if(i % 3 == 0) { System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText()); }
            else if(i % 4 == 0) { System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText()); }
            else if(i % 5 == 0) { System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText()); }
        }
```

Obviously this is wrong, because my `% 3` will print the 9th element, `% 4` will print the 16th element, etc.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this, so any advice to point me in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: tableElems acts like array?

Comment: @Ali tableElems is a list. I will include it above. I am using selenium webdriver to pull the values out of a table.

Comment: you need something likke (for (i = 4; i<= myList.length; I= 9) { ...i is your starting index now ) I try to rewrite in Java now

Comment: What is your goal for this question? Is the printed output is your goal or the Java algorithm to pick those number is your goal?

Comment: The algorithm. There are many more entries to the table than are shown.

Comment: If the values in your table are always incremented by one, there is actually no need to retrieve them. You can just loop and compute the value mathematically then when your computed value overflow your array's maximum you stop. This would allow you to save 66% of iterations compared to the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for (int i = 3; i<tableElems.size(); i++) {
    if (((i / 3) % 3) == 1) { System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText()); }
}
```

Think about this as dividing into groups of nine, and further dividing each group of 9 into groups of 3. on the second group of 3 (i.e. 3-5, 12-14) it will display.

Comment: This gave me an infinite loop of 4's. I like this approach though - I may try to improve it if you don't revise it.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's possible for it to print 4 more than once - by the nature of the for loop. Try System.out.println(i); and see if the indices are working?

Comment: Infinite loop of 3's, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to help you then :/ it worked for me when i tried it!

Comment: Must have been a copy error? I'm not sure. I tried it two times yesterday - both ending in an infinite loop. I really like this solution though - thank you. This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Short and simple. Great job.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int offset = 4;
 int width = 3;
```

advice:

for each row in table check offset + width is under the row width, and then start from offset + 0, offset + 1 upto offset + width

and continue this loop for all the row of table

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that tableElems is a list, so I assume it's akin to a single-dimension array, rather than what appears to be a multi-dimensional table like you've laid out(I assume for visual purposes).

You're right by starting the **for** loop at i = 3. The easiest way, IMO, to do this is to just bump the loop ahead several spaces in the array after you've printed three elements. Here's my solution using C# and an array; you should be able to convert it to Java pretty easily.

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 3; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (counter < 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        i += 5;  // we are incrementing by one on the next pass, so this can be 5  
        counter = 0;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yes, your assumption of it being single-dimensional is correct.

Comment: Where does `Console.WriteLine` comes from ?

Comment: Console.WriteLine() is used by C# to write out to the console. It's functionally equivalent to Java's System.out.println(). OP had specified Java, so I'll confess I had already written it out and was feeling slightly lazy with respect to converting it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to `%`, then this should work

```
int rowSize = 9;
for (int i = 0; i < tableElems.size(); i++) {

    int column = i % rowSize;

    if (column >=3 && column <= 5) {
        System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why loop from 0, if we know OP wants to start with 4th element ?

Comment: I just made it so it looks more like a general solution. So it is a little bit easier to adapt to other indices.

Comment: Your algorithm will iterate 36 times, an algorithm where only 12 iterations would happen exists.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Java code

```
for (int i = 3; i<tableElems.size(); i += 9) {
    System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText());
    System.out.println(tableElems.get(i+1).getText());
    System.out.println(tableElems.get(i+2).getText());
    System.out.println(tableElems.get(i+3).getText());
}
```

If you are creating a larger pattern:

```
int starting = 3;
int nextStartDistance = 9;
int waveCount = 3;

for (int i = starting; i<tableElems.size(); i += nextStartDistance) {
    for (int b = 0; b <= waveCount; b ++) {
        System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText());
    }

}
```

This code is written in JavaScript, but the algorithm considered:

```
var list =[
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,
27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35];

for (var index = 3; index <= list.length; index +=9 ) {
    var a = list[index];
    var b = list[index+1];
    var c = list[index+2];
    var d = list[index+3];
    console.log(a,b,c,d);
}
```

Result will be what you expected:

```
// 3 4 5 6
// 12 13 14 15
// 21 22 23 24
// 30 31 32 33
// user:~$
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for the reply. My table is actually much much larger than this. There are about 500 entries in this table, I just cut it down to scale to prove the point of the pattern I am going for.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 3; i < tableElems.size(); i += 9) {
    for (int j = i; j < i + 3 && j < tableElems.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(tableElems.get(j).getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this would be very close to your code:

```
for (int i = 3; i < tableElems.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText());
        } else if ((i % 3) == 1) {
            System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText());
        } else if ((i % 3) == 2) {
            System.out.println(tableElems.get(i).getText());
            i = i + 6;
        }
    }
```

i just adapted your modulo and skip 6 elements every time i hit the last one to print out

furthermore its quite effective because all unneeded elements are just skipped instead of iterated and checked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only care about the values out of your table and the html structure is standard html tags as shown on your questions, then you can use css selector to select appropriate values.

```
chrome.findElements(By.cssSelector("td:nth-child(4),td:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(6)"))
```

Please note that css nth-child selector is 1 based.